# How to pass key:value onChange from select-option in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, select, html-select, redux-toolkit

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKDfKbLJkZQ&t=106s) and try to modify it a little.

I have this code addRequestForm.js

```
import { BiPlus } from 'react-icons/bi'
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query"
import { addRequest, getRequests } from "../../lib/helper"
import Bug from "./bugRequest"
import Success from "./successRequest"


export default function AddRequestForm({ formData, setFormData }) {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const addMutation = useMutation(addRequest, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.prefetchQuery('requests', getRequests)
        }
    })

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (Object.keys(formData).length == 0) return console.log("Don't have Form Data");
        let { sector, contact_name } = formData;

        const model = {
            sector, contact_name
        }

        addMutation.mutate(model)
    }

    if (addMutation.isLoading) return <div>Loading!</div>
    if (addMutation.isError) return <Bug message={addMutation.error.message}></Bug>
    if (addMutation.isSuccess) return <Success message={"Added Successfully"}></Success>


    return (
        <form className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 w-4/6 gap-4 md:px-4 md:mx-auto" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            
            <div className="input-type">
                <label htmlFor="sector" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    Sector
                </label>
                <select
                    id="sector"
                    name="sector"
                    autoComplete="sector-name"
                    className="border w-full px-5 py-3 focus:outline-none rounded-md"
                    
                    onChange={(e) => setFormData({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
               
                >
                    <option value="North">North</option>
                    <option value="South">South</option>
                    <option value="West">West</option>
                    <option value="East">East</option>
                    {/*  */}
                </select>
            </div>


            <div className="form-control input-type">
                <label className="input-group">
                    <span>Contact Name</span>
                    <input type="text" onChange={setFormData} name="contact_name" placeholder="Contact Name Here..“ className="w-full input input-bordered" />
                </label>
            </div>



            <button type="submit" className="flex justify-center text-md w-2/6 bg-green-500 text-white px-4 py-2 border rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-green-500 hover:text-green-500">
                Add <span className="px-1"><BiPlus size={24}></BiPlus></span>
            </button>

        </form >
    )


}
```

For name=“contact_name” already succeed insert into database (mongodb + mongoose). But, I’m still confuse, how to do the same to select-option?

Already tried these:

```
onChange={(e) => setFormData({ e.target.name: e.target.value })}
onChange={(e) => setFormData({ sector.name: e.target.value })}
onChange={(e) => setFormData({ [e.target.name][0]: e.target.value })}
```

Got Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ",". While I thought this is the right value when I’m consoling these ( result: “sector:myname”).

```
onChange={(e) => setFormData({ sector: e.target.value })}
onChange={(e) => setFormData({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
```

No insert into database.

How to write it correctly? I’m using nextjs (i thought the same with reactjs, right?) + @reduxjs/toolkit 1.9.1.

In case needed, here is reducer.js:

```
import UpdateRequestForm from "./updateRequestForm";
import AddRequestForm from "./addRequestForm";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useReducer } from "react";

const formReducer = (state, event) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        [event.target?.name]: event.target?.value
    }
}

export default function FormRequest() {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {})
    const formId = useSelector((state) => state.app.client.formId)

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto py-5">
            {formId ? UpdateRequestForm({ formId, formData, setFormData }) : AddRequestForm({ formData, setFormData })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, just use this syntax:

```
…
 value={formData.sector}
 onChange={setFormData}
…
```

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        onChange = {(e) => { 
                          let obj = {} ; 
                          obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
                          setFormData(obj);
                
                       } 
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no luck with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely following your use case for the reducer but you could replace it with a simple handleChange function as follows. Just a side note, calling `setFormData(//newData)` will complete erase what is in there so we first spread the original state and change the value based on the `key`.

State and handleChange:

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    sector: "North",
    contact_name: ""
  });


const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
  // Deconstruct the target
  // Deconstruct the name and value from the target
  const { name, value } = target;
  // Set the state
  setFormData((previousState) => ({
    ...previousState,
    [name]: value,
  }));
};
```

Usage:

```
  <select
    placeholder="Select a sector"
    name="sector"
    value={formData.sector}
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
    <option value="West">West</option>
    <option value="East">East</option>
  </select>

  <input
    value={formData.contact_name}
    placeholder="Contact Name"
    name="contact_name"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```

A codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-kilby-emcyl4?file=/src/App.js:461-615

Also note that you will need to assign a name to the input element. In the example, name is set to sector. As the name value will be used to indicate which key in the state object must be updated.

It's good practice to have controlled input fields. So setting the value of the input to your state will accomplish this. Only thing to remember is you need a default state. I have added it all to the codesandbox if you would like to take a look.

Comment: I’m still noob, sorry. I tried this too, and put handleChange codes above handleSubmit. But still, not inserted into database. But the contact_name does.

Comment: Have you done a console.log on the req.body to see whether or not the value is being received

Comment: How to do that? Already tried  onChange={(e) => { console.log(e.target.value), console.log(sector.name) }} and they exist.

Comment: FrontEnd makes HTTP request with data as a payload to the backend-> backend controller receives the payload -> payload lives inside the `request.body` -> controller dictates what it does with the data (You code this) . So if your value is loggin in the front end. It's going missing somewhere either in the initial HTTP request or somewhere in the backend when it's received.

Comment: What about this:
1. input type="text" onChange={setFormData} name="contact_name" => this is work, data passed to database
2. select  id="sector"  onChange={setFormData} name="sector"  => this is not work, data not passed to database

Comment: I console log like this: 
onChange={(e) => {console.log(e.target.value), console.log(sektor.name), console.log([e.target.name][0])} and the results are correct, eg. “North”, “sector”, “sector”. 


And all of these are okay, but I dont know how to code it.

Comment: Please add the `handleChange` that I suggested to your `contact_name` as well. It looks like your `contact_name` input is overwriting the state. That should solve it. I will update the codeSandbox and answer